# Assigning driving directions on a road

Tags: geometry

This is a road, where people drive on the left side:

[image]

Everyone knows exactly what direction to drive in, no matter where on the road they are.

Consider a more 'complicated' shape, like a circular road:

[image]

People can still drive on the correct (left) side of the road (locally speaking), no matter where they are.

Now I'm wondering, are there any exotic road shapes (not necessarily physically realizable) where one *cannot* assign a well-defined driving direction at each point on the road, in a smooth way? (I mean, there'll definitely be a line of discontinuity along the divider where driving direction flips, but apart from that). Let's say that intersections are not allowed.

How would these ideas be formulated mathematically?

Comment: Maybe you can use a [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) to define it. Given a vector perpendicular to the road surface pointing upwards, and a vector in the direction of travel (imagine both of these pointing from a spot in the middle of the road) then their cross product points to the side of the road where you should drive. The only place where you could not do this is where there is no continuous road surface so that no upwards direction can be defined.

Comment: Interesting point, but let's say the road surface is always continuous... I have an idea, how about a mobius strip? Can people drive consistently on a mobius strip-shaped road?

Comment: Yes, they can. Try it out!